# What do opens in the product topology over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ look like?

Tags: general-topology, p-adic-number-theory, product-space

Let $p$ be a prime, let $\pi_n : \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ be the obvious projection and 
$$\mathbb{Z}_p = \{\, x \in \Pi_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \,|\, \forall k\geq 1:  \pi_k(x_{k+1}) = x_k \,\}$$
the p-adic integers.

Endow $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete topology and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ with the product topology.

Now, if I'm not mistaken, open sets in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ are now given as (unions of) $\Pi_n S_n$ with only finitely many $S_n$ not equal to $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$. However, this is clearly inconsistent with the requirement on $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$ that $\pi_n(x_{n+1}) = x_n$ (since we can pick $n$ large enough so we can choose, say, $\pi_n(x_{n+1}) = x_n+1$, since only finitely many $S_n$ place any effective restrictions on the choice of $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$).

So what do open sets in the product topology on $\mathbb{Z}_p$ look like?

Comment: I read it as "Endow $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ with the product topology and look at $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as a subspace of it". Am I wrong? Does it change something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, there is an important subtlety: $\Bbb Z_p$ is just a subset of the direct product, so "the product topology" on it makes no sense. Instead, one endows it with the *subspace topolog*y of the product topology.

Spelled out, this means that a set $X \subseteq \Bbb Z_p$ is open iff it can be written as $\Bbb Z_p \cap \tilde X$ where $\tilde X$ is an open set of $\prod_{n\ge 1} \Bbb Z/p^n$ with the product topology. Spelled out further and using your correct description of the product topology, that means that $X \subseteq \Bbb Z_p$ is open iff for every $x \in X$ there is some set of the form $\Bbb Z_p \cap \prod_n S_n$ *with finitely many $S_n$ not equal to $\Bbb Z/p^n$* containing $x$ and contained in $X$. Now say $k_{x, X}$ is a number such that all those $S_n = \Bbb Z/p^n$ for $n \ge k$, you see this means that with $x$ also $x + p^{k_{x, X}} \Bbb Z_p \subseteq X$, and that is one standard description of open sets in $\Bbb Z_p$.

Loosely speaking, a basic open set containing a consistent sequence $x =(x_k)_k \in \Bbb Z_p$ is of the form "every consistent sequence $(y_k)_k$ such that $y_k=x_k$ for (at least) finitely many $k$".

Comment: Thanks! In your last sentence, do you mean $y_k = x_k$ for at least all $k$ up to some $k_{x,X}$? Because of course $x$ agrees with itself for an infinite amount of $k$.

Comment: Yes, at least finitely many.